For a fixed a permutation, prove that composition with all permutation will give all permutation
One of our exercises had this. Prove that for all $\sigma \in \Pi_{n}$
\begin{align*}
\Pi_{n} = \{\sigma\rho : \rho \in \Pi_{n}\} = \{\rho\sigma : \rho \in \Pi_{n}\}
\end{align*}
MY APPROACH
Take any $\sigma \in \Pi_{n}$ define a function $f : \Pi_{n} \rightarrow \Pi_{n}$ such that $f(\rho) = \sigma\rho$. If I can prove that $f$ is bijective then I am done. Now consider $\rho_{1}, \rho_{2} \in \Pi_{n}$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(\rho_{1}) = f(\rho_{2}) \\
\implies \sigma\rho_{1} = \sigma\rho_{2} \\
\implies \forall \: x \in [n] : \sigma\rho_{1}(x) = \sigma\rho_{2}(x) \\
\implies \forall \: x \in [n] : \rho_{1}(x) = \rho_{2}(x)
\end{align*}
which implies $\rho_{1} = \rho_{2}$ (I have used the fact that $\sigma$ is bijective) which shows that $f$ is injective. Now consider any permutation $q \in \Pi_{n}$ we have $\forall \: x \in [n] : q(x) \in [n]$ means I have
\begin{align*}
\forall \: x \in [n], \exists \: y \in [n] : q(x) = \sigma(y)
\end{align*}
Define a transposition $\tau$ which swaps $x,y$ that is $\tau(x) = y$ which implies I can write
\begin{align*}
\forall \: x \in [n], \exists \: y \in [n] : q(x) = \sigma(\tau(x))
\end{align*}
which means $q = \sigma\tau$ which shows that $f$ is surjective and hence bijective. This completes $\Pi_{n} = \{\sigma\rho : \rho : \Pi_{n}\}$.
For the other part, I prove that $\Pi_{n} = \{\rho\sigma : \rho : \Pi_{n}\}$. Take any $\sigma \in \Pi_{n}$ define a function $g : \Pi_{n} \rightarrow \Pi_{n}$ such that $g(\rho) = \rho\sigma$. So consider
\begin{align*}
\rho_{1}\sigma = \rho_{2}\sigma \\
\rho_{1}\sigma\sigma^{-1} = \rho_{2}\sigma\sigma^{-1} \\
\rho_{1} = \rho_{2}
\end{align*}
which shows that $g$ is injective. Take any $q \in \Pi_{n}$ I have
\begin{align*}
q = q \sigma^{-1} \sigma \\
q = \rho \sigma
\end{align*}
implying that $g$ is surjective and hence bijective.
Is this proof correct ? While I was doing the first part, I got the idea for second and that's the reason the steps in second part reduced as lot.

To show that $f$ is a bijection you also could consider $g$ defined by $g(\rho):=\sigma^{-1}\rho$ and prove that $f\circ g=g\circ f=\text{id}$.
